# How to return documents from firebase with specific variables?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to view documents only with Number is less than or equal to 10 (not to show all documents).
here is my code:

```
Future getHomeWsyl()async{ 
    var firestore = Firestore.instance;         
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await firestore.collection("HomePageWsyl").getDocuments();  
    return snapshot.documents;
}
```

what to correct in this code to do this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8Ix6.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To only get a limit number of documents, use the [`limit` method](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/limit.html).

So something like:

```
firestore.collection("HomePageWsyl").limit(10).getDocuments();
```

---

To only get documents where a field matches a certain condition, use the [`where` method](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/where.html).

So something like:

```
firestore.collection("HomePageWsyl").where("Number", isLessThanOrEqualTo: 10).getDocuments();
```

This means that your documents must have a field named `Number` with a numeric value.

---

I recommend getting familiar with the Firestore documentation on [queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) and [ordering and limiting data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data), and with the reference documentation for the [`cloud_firestore` package](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore), specifically the [`Query` class](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query-class.html).

Comment: I tired the one but didn't worked for me:-  `firestore.collection("HomePageWsyl").where("Number", isLessThanOrEqualTo: 10).getDocuments(); `

Comment: Do your documents have a `"Number" field? If not, the query is meaningless. If they do: what didn't work about the code for you? Please be explicit about what you tried with that code. It's typically also helpful if you show a screenshot of a document in the Firebase console in your question. In fact, that's usually much more helpful than seeing the output of your app.

Comment: in my fiebaase i made Number to string and should be number, solved for me thanks

Answer (score 0):

firestore.collection("HomePageWsyl").where("Number", isLessThanOrEqualTo: 10).getDocuments();
and in firebase "Number" should be number